# How to get an AWS Feature Store feature group into the ACTIVE state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-sagemaker, data-ingestion, aws-feature-store

I am trying to ingest some rows into a Feature Store on AWS using:

```py
feature_group.ingest(data_frame=df, max_workers=8, wait=True)
```

but I am getting the following error:

> Failed to ingest row 1: An error occurred (ValidationError) when
> calling the PutRecord operation: Validation Error: FeatureGroup
> [feature-group] is not in ACTIVE state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the status of a feature group after its creation is `Created` but before you can ingest any rows you need to simply wait until it's `Active`:

```py
while status != 'Created':
        try:
            status = feature_group.describe()['OfflineStoreStatus']['Status']
        except:
            pass
        print('Offline store status: {}'.format(status))    
        sleep(15)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, contrary to what the error message says it was actually a permissions error.  Adding the "AmazonSageMakerFeatureStoreAccess" permission to the role that's running the code, and then rerunning it worked for me.